# Selenium Sending Keys to a search field is visible working but does not return any result. But It works if I type into this input field by hand

Tags: java, selenium

This is how I send "Amsterdam" into the field. But it shows no result. I also tried to .clear() the field.

```
    WebElement flyToSearch = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'select2-search__field')]"));
    flyToSearch.sendKeys("Amsterdam");
    flyToSearch.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

[image]

But if I type it by hand. It returns the result. I did the same thing for the search field right next to it.  It worked fine.

[image]

Here below I close the log in pop up first. Then box for one-way flight tickets is selected. Then I set the origin to Istanbul. But I can not set destination to Amsterdam or any other city.

```
private static final WebDriver webDriver = WebDriverReady.getWebClient();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        openPage();
        closeLogin();
        selectOneWay();
        fillFlyFrom();
        fillFlyTo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        webDriver.close();
    }
}

private static void openPage() {
    webDriver.get(PegasusConstants.URL);
}

private static void closeLogin() {
    webDriver.findElement(By.className("nxm2_bolbol-login_header")).click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void selectOneWay() {
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@for, 'one_way')]")).click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void fillFlyFrom() {
    WebElement flyFrom = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@for, 'fs_from')]"));
    WebElement parentOfFlyFrom = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
            "return arguments[0].parentNode;", flyFrom);
    parentOfFlyFrom.click();

    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement flyFromSearch = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'select2-search__field')]"));
    flyFromSearch.sendKeys("Istanbul");
    flyFromSearch.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void fillFlyTo() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("nxm2CookieSubmitButton"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='From']/preceding-sibling::span/descendant::span[@role='presentation']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.select2-search__field"))).sendKeys("Amsterdam");

    List<WebElement> sourceOptions = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul li[role='treeitem']"));
    for (WebElement ele : sourceOptions) {
        ele.click();
    }
//        WebElement flyTo = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nereye']"));
//        WebElement parentOfFlyTo = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
//                "return arguments[0].parentNode;", flyTo);
//        parentOfFlyTo.click();
//
//        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//
//        WebElement flyToSearch =
//                new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20)
//                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'select2-search__field')]")));
//        flyToSearch.sendKeys("Amsterdam");
//        flyToSearch.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
//
//        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

What could be the problem here? Thanks

Comment: Is the page url public ?

Comment: When you sending keys manually - does suggested options appearing below the text input so you should select one of them?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes it is public. https://www.flypgs.com/en

Comment: @Prophet yes as I type, it filters out the selections. Even if I removed the last character by clicking on backspace after selenium filled the field with "Amstedam". It becomes visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code once.

Click on the `to` field, send `Amsterdam` and then select `Amsterdam`from the list.

```
driver.get("https://www.flypgs.com/en");

//Select "One-way"              
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='one_way']"))).click();

//Select "From"     
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@id='fligth-searh']/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/span[1]/span"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='Istanbul-S.Gokcen']"))).click();

//Select "to"       
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@id='fligth-searh']/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/span"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='select2-search__field']"))).sendKeys("Amsterdam");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='Amsterdam']"))).click();

//Click on "search"     
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='SEARCH CHEAP FLIGHTS']"))).click();

//Click on "I Agree"        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='I Agree']"))).click();
```

Comment: Again it shows no result.
 Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //li[text()='Amsterdam'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

but it works when I manually click one of the "empty" spaces on the web page and then click "to". It is automatically writes "Amsterdam" again but this time it lists it and then the rest is working as intended. :/

Comment: @Thunfische - I don't get any exceptions, when I execute this code. I have to do nothing manually.

Comment: I am using the latest version of ChromeDriver as instance of webdriver. What do you use?

Comment: @Thunfische - This is the [Compete Code](https://pastebin.com/AteKUD2Y).

Answer (score 0):

This could be cause element is not rendered properly and you are trying to interact with it. Please try with Explicit waits :

```
WebElement flyToSearch = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'select2-search__field')]")));
flyToSearch.sendKeys("Amsterdam");
flyToSearch.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

or with **JS** :

```
WebElement flyToSearch = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'select2-search__field')]")));
(JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Amsterdam')", flyToSearch)
```

**Udpate 1 :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.flypgs.com/en");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("nxm2CookieSubmitButton"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='From']/preceding-sibling::span/descendant::span[@role='presentation']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.select2-search__field"))).sendKeys("Amsterdam");

List<WebElement> sourceOptions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul li[role='treeitem']"));
for (WebElement ele : sourceOptions) {
    ele.click();
}
```

Comment: The outcome is the same. Amsterdam is written but there is no result :/

Comment: @Thunfische :  Check the updated 1 code above.

Comment: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //label[text()='From']/preceding-sibling::span/descendant::span[@role='presentation'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
I will update my question with the entire code

Comment: the above code that I have given is for `From` not `To`